# C# return an a class

Tags: c#, class, fluorinefx

I'm using FluorineFx to send/receive AMF3 data over server.

```
 netConnection.Call("my-amf", "zend", "Ka_Services_Park", "getCompleteParkOfUser", new GetCustomersHandler(), new object[] { "msg_2580671638", "20251876" });

    public class GetCustomersHandler : IPendingServiceCallback
    {
        public void ResultReceived(IPendingServiceCall call)
        {
            object result = call.Result;
        }
    }
```

i want to return response from class GetCustomersHandler to class from was called
i called GetCustomersHandler in netConnection.Call in Form1 class, i want to return/get response (object result) from GetCustomersHandler to Form1.

Comment: When you see these kind of non .Net things (such as flash stuff) and how they're used (such as having a LOT of magic strings in a single method call) is when you realize how much they actually suck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your callback object store the result as a property.

```
public class GetCustomersHandler : IPendingServiceCallback
{
    GetCustomersHandler()
    {
        this.Signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void ResultReceived(IPendingServiceCall call)
    {
        this.Result = call.Result;
        this.Signal.Set();
    }

    public ManualResetEvent Signal { get; protected set; }
    public object Result { get; protected set; }
}
```

In the calling function, hold on to your callback object.  Then when `netConnection.Call()` returns, you can retrieve the value

```
GetCustomersHandler callback = new GetCustomersHandler();
netConnection.Call("my-amf", "zend", "Ka_Services_Park", "getCompleteParkOfUser", callback, new object[] { "msg_2580671638", "20251876" });
callback.WaitOne();
object result = callback.Result;
```

Comment: I tried something like you posted, but there is little(?) problem, 
object result = callback.Result; is calling before GetCustomersHandler, i don't know why, but in effect returned result = null :/

Comment: is `netConnection.Call(...)` asyncronous?  If so, then you'll have to wait for it to complete.

Comment: Ok, i make simple sleep thread after netConnection.Call and it's worked.

Comment: Sleep may be unreliable.  Add a signal to your class (like `ManualResetEvent`).  Set the event when your callback is called.  Wait for your event in your calling function, then get the result.

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for possible asynchronous issues.